# How does yarn manage the extra resources in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

Consider there are 3 top level queues, q1,q2,q3.Capacity Scheduler

Users of q1 and q2 submit their jobs to their respective queues, they are guaranteed to get their allocated resources. Now the resources which are not utilized by q3 has to be utilized by q1 and q2. What factors does yarn consider while dividing the extra resources? Who (q1,q2) gets preference?

Answer (score 0):

Every queue in the Capacity Scheduler has 2 important properties (which are defined in terms of percentage of total resources available), which determine the scheduling:

- Guaranteed capacity of the queue (determined by configuration "**yarn.scheduler.capacity.{queue-path}.capacity"**)
- Maximum capacity to which the queue can grow (determined by the configuration **"yarn.scheduler.capacity.{queue-path}.maximum-capacity"**). This puts an upper limit on the resource utilization by a queue. The queue cannot grow beyond this limit.

The Capacity Scheduler, organizes the queues in a hierarchical fashion. 
Queues are of 2 types **"parent"** and **"leaf"** queues. The jobs can only be submitted to the **leaf** queues.

**"ROOT"** queue is the parent of all the other queues.

Each parent queue, sorts the child queues based on the demand (what's the current used capacity of the queue? Whether it is under-served or over-served?).

For each queue, the ratio **(Used Capacity / Total Cluster Capacity)** gives an indication about the utilization of the queue. ***The parent queue always gives priority to the most under-served child queue.***.

When the free resources are given to a parent queue, the resources are recursively distributed to the child queues, depending on the current used capacity of the queue.

Within a leaf queue, the distribution of capacity can happen based on certain user limits (for e.g. configuration parameter: **yarn.scheduler.capacity.{queue-path}.minimum-user-limit-percent**, determines the minimum queue capacity that each user is guaranteed to have).

In your example, for the sake of simplicity, let's assume that the queues q1, q2 and q3 are directly present under "ROOT". As mentioned earlier, the parent queue keeps the queues sorted based on their utilization.

Since q3 is not utilized at all, the parent can distribute the un-utilized resources of q3, between q1 and q2.

The available resources are distributed based on following factors:

1. If both q1 and q2 have enough resources to continue scheduling their jobs, then there is no need to distribute the available resources from q3
2. If both q1 and q2 have hit maximum capacity (**"yarn.scheduler.capacity.{queue-path}.maximum-capacity"**, this configuration limits the elasticity of the queues. Queues cannot demand more than the percentage configured by this parameter), then the free resources are not allotted
3. If any one of the queues q1 or q2 is under-served, then the free resources are allotted to the under-served queue
4. If both q1 and q2 are under-served, then the most under-served queue is given the top priority.